# How do I get maven artifacts into the Jenkins maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm somewhat new to Maven and Jenkins working together.

I have a project that builds a JAR, and the JAR along with its attendant files (pom, sha1, md5, etc) are made available via the Maven repository that Jenkins can host. I can see these files when I navigate to my build machine, for example:

```
http://myhostname:8080/plugin/repository/everything/com/example/projectname/0.7/
```

One member of my team has a build target of a shaded JAR that other projects need. I'd like to get this shaded JAR into the Maven repository, too. In the pom.xml, this line controls what the shaded JAR is called:

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-with-dependencies</finalName>
```

And in my project, I'd then be able to do:

```
"com.example" % "projectname-with-dependencies" % "0.7" (I suspect - yes?)
```

That seems okay to me - any clue on how I tell Jenkins to take this JAR out of the target folder (where it is properly put after the build is done) and make it available in the Maven repository suitable for inclusion by other projects?

I hope this makes sense and I can get a little adult supervision ;)

EDIT - as requested, the relevant portion of the pom.xml in the  section:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-with-dependencies</finalName>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.example.projectname.Projectname</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>

                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: How is the shaded JAR being built?  Is it also a maven project?

Comment: It is a goal in the pom.xml file. The JAR is put in the target directory along with the project's JAR. That is, the target directory then has project-0.7.jar and project-0.7-with-dependencies.jar and I'd like BOTH of these available via Jenkins's Maven repository.

Comment: So I'm assuming that a maven install only actually installs the project jar, not the shaded jar?

Comment: Correct. The shaded JAR is built, but then that appears to be it.

Comment: Can you post the pom.xml file that is used for the shaded jar project?  I'm wondering if you are just not running the maven-shade-plugin as part of the proper phase that Jenkins is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a work-around that I think should work in your case (though I've used it for a slightly different purpose).

We have one project, ProjectAbcd, that contains the source code, resources, etc., that is used to build the regular (non-shaded) jar.  The pom for this project does not contain the maven-shade-plugin, as we're not doing the shading here.

We then create a second project, with a slightly different name and artifactID,  ProjectAbcdWithDependencies, that is empty except for a rather simple pom  file.  That pom file lists just a single dependency (ProjectAbcd), and includes the maven-shade-plugin.  For the shade-plugin, it does not set the final-name, like you do above, because the artifactId already contains the "WithDependencies" suffix.

When maven packages this second project, it will pull down the orignal one, grab all the  original's dependencies, and shade them all together in a single jar whose name will derived from the pom's artifactId.  Any install or release step that follows should then work out of the box.

Here is the pom of the first project:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectAbcd</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>8.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ProjectAbcd</name>
...
</project>
```

More importantly, here is the one from the second project:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectAbcdWithDependencies</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>8.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ProjectAbcdWithDependencies</name>
...
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectAbcd</artifactId>
  <version>8.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: This worked! And the side benefit is that we can now use different branches for the fully-shaded vs. non-shaded to allow different consumers to be on different development paths (yeah, sounds wonky, but having the fully-shaded JAR be on our bleeding-edge unstable branch is helpful with this project. Nice side effect)

Answer (score 1):

I expect what you'll need to do is add another maven build step to Jenkins after the main build step, which uses the install:install-file goal to manually install the shaded jar.

At this point you can treat the shaded jar as just another 3rd party jar which needs to be installed manually using the [maven-install-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

e.g.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<project-path>/target/<shaded-jar>
```

Since the shadowed jar file was built by maven, it'll have its pom.xml embedded in the jar file, so maven will pick it up automatically and install into the right place in your local repository.

Comment: This almost works.

[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Tokenizer/workspace/target/projectname-0.7-with-dependencies.jar to /home/cambler/.m2/repository/com/example/projectname/0.7/projectname-0.7.jar

So this is putting it in my local repository.

I want it in the Maven repository that Jenkins serves.

URL http://myhostname:8080/plugin/repository for example.

Comment: tl;dr above: it's installing it in my local repository, not the repository server that Jenkins provides

Comment: You can specify the repo with the `-DlocalRepositoryPath=<some-path>` option. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) for the full docs on the install plugin.

Comment: Also, just FYI for anyone else, install:install-file MAY NOT use the latest version suitable for picking up the data from the POM I've found. To ensure that it does, use org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file

Comment: Still not working. Now it is using the path as an actual path, not the server. So I get this: [INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace/target/projectname-0.7-with-dependencies.jar to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace/http:/hostname:8080/plugin/repository/com/example/projectname/0.7/projectname-0.7.jar

Comment: The hostname:8080 part won't be in the filesystem path.  The url is how you ask hudson to serve up a file.  The actual path will most likely be something like `<hudson-install-dir>/plugins/maven3-plugin/repository` or something like that.  You need to go poke around in your hudson install's plugins and find the actual path to the repository.

Comment: Yeah - no such repository. The server apparently doesn't actually store the jars, it references them in the actual target directory of the workspace. There's no place to copy it to.

That's the source of the problem - how do you tell the Jenkins Maven Repository plugin to expose *ALL* artifacts.